# json_config file problem in json c library

Tags: c, json, embedded, stm32, keil

i am working on a stm32 project and my IDE is keil.
and i want to use json c for data saving in sd card.
i downloaded json c library from git, after that i included json.h file to my project after compilation i found a error that json_config.h no such file.
what is the problem in this library?

```
#ifndef _json_inttypes_h_
#define _json_inttypes_h_


#include "json_config.h"

#ifdef JSON_C_HAVE_INTTYPES_H
/* inttypes.h includes stdint.h */
#include <inttypes.h>

#else
#include <stdint.h>

#define PRId64 "I64d"
#define SCNd64 "I64d"

#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Where is the library installed? Perhaps you should be using `#include <json_config.h>` (note angle-brackets `<>`)? And if it's installed in a non-"standard" location (where the compiler doesn't look by default) you need to inform the compiler about its location (but I don't know how to do it with the Keil compiler, please read its documentation).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: No doubt there are many JSON libraries on "git". (Presumably you meant "githib"?).  You'll need to be more specific than that.

Comment: The library at https://github.com/json-c/json-c appears to be the one you are referring to.  It has two files `json_config.h.in` and `json_config.h.win32`. rename the first one perhaps?  Presumably that would be done by the chosen build system if you were building on a supported platform.  It is quite likely that you will have other issues porting this code to a bare-metal STM32 environment.  Something like https://zserge.com/jsmn/ may be more appropriate.

Comment: The presence of .in file and the build instructions at that repository indicate that there is an autoconfiguration process which must be performed before the code can be compiled.  Although the code itself might work, it is probably not meant to be cross compiled to small embedded systems and would likely require a lot of work to adapt it for use there.